# Gmail API: Timeout errors on sending emails

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

We have a node app that sends emails via the Gmail API running on a Digital Ocean server. Today, we've started seeing timeout and server unreachable errors when calling the API, but haven't been able to reproduce these. They seem to happen to around 30-40% of requests we make to Google. Here are example error responses:

```
{"code":"ETIMEDOUT","errno":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"172.217.6.205","port":443}

{"code":"ENETUNREACH","errno":"ENETUNREACH","syscall":"connect","address":"2607:f8b0:4006:805::200d","port":443}
```

We're not exceeding a gmail API quota and I don't see any other messages as to why Google would reject our requests. Any ideas as to what is happening here?

Comment: can happen if your access token is expired

Comment: Thanks but I've double checked these queries locally and haven't had any problems running them.

Comment: This error may not be connected to your Gmail API, but more on the Node.js configuration. You will receive this error if you didn't received the request response in a given time. You may want to check this related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23633266/5995040) which talks about the timeout module of nodejs. There are also some advise on creating option how to handle this kind of error. Hope this helps.