# How to handle ETIMEDOUT in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've developed a Node.js/Express.js application that interacts with a FTP server, the problem is that if the server is offline the application crashes because I can't find a way to handle the ETIMEDOUT exception. The module I'm using for FTP is jsftp, by the way.

The part of the code where it happens looks like this:

```
router.post("/", upload, function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        ftp.auth(ftp.user, ftp.pass, function(error) {
            if(error) {
                res.status("500");
                res.end("Error: Couldn't authenticate into the FTP server.");
                console.log(error);
            } else {    // Authenticated successfully into the FTP server
                /* some code here */
            }
        });
    } catch(error) {    // Probably timeout error
        res.status("500");
        res.end("Internal Server Error");
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

I tried appending a `.on('error', function(e) { /* my code here */ }` to the router.post function, but then I get `TypeError: router.post(...).on is not a function`.

Does anyone have any suggestion? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to handle exceptions in a jsftp connection, it's very similar to what [@neo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2731417/neo) proposed, but you gotta use your connection instance.

This is what has worked:

```
let conn = new jsftp(ftp);

conn.on("error", function(error) {  // If an exception was thrown throughout the FTP connection
    // Handle the error in here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You issue is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632914/how-to-handle-etimedout-error)

The steps are to handle the error and to retry.

```
http.Client.on('error', function (err) { 
    /* handle errors here */ 
    if (err.message.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') { 
        /* apply logic to retry */ }
})
```

use [node-retry](https://github.com/tim-kos/node-retry) to keep the retry logic simple.

Comment: Attempting that gives me "TypeError: express.on is not a function", even though Express is properly imported in my code with "const express = require("express");".

Comment: sorry, its it is part of `http.Client` which you can [find more information here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback). The `express` was a typo