# Non blocking socket connect() get errno ETIMEDOUT-Connection timed out

Tags: c, sockets, connection-timeout, errno

I have a non-blocking IPv4 TCP socket, when I try to connect(), I get the errno ETIMEDOUT. It confused me a lot, since I have not set timeout on socket. What is some possible reasons of this case?

Comment: Are you sure the socket is non-blocking? I would not expect this error when doing a `connect`  on a non-blocking socket but instead `EINPROGRESS`.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich it is possible to fail the fnctl() since I have not done error check at fnctl() return value, however, if it is failed, then it should be blocking forever, since I have not set the timeout value.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Also, suppose fnctl() failed, it fails always. Since my system has retry mechanism. If fails, socket will be closed and then create a new, set non blocking again. How it is possible that other options set correctly except fnctl(). It is a rare case that fnctl() failed in my opinion.

Comment: Based on what you write it seems to be that your code is missing error checks and you don't really know exactly where this problem comes from. I think you need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that one can look at what really causes the problem instead of just making (maybe unfounded) assumptions.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich From logic reasoning, I am sure it is non blocking. I will check the Linux kernel. My kernel is not a standard Linux kernel, probably it has some strange thing maybe. So thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From `man` page:

> ETIMEDOUT:
>
> Timeout while attempting connection.  The server may be too busy to
> accept new connections.  Note that for IP sockets the timeout may be
> very long when syncookies are enabled on the server.

You can also see ETIMEDOUT in this quesiton [How to handle ETIMEDOUT error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632914/how-to-handle-etimedout-error)